# Get pages that are only under letters in category

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api, wikimedia

When somebody opens wikipedia category, he can observe pages, that are organized alphabetically and are under the letter (A,B,C, etc.).

For example

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Countries_in_Europe

But there are also some related pages, that are situated under asterisk sign(*), dot(.) or just at the top. How can I extract only those pages, that are under letters?

Or may be somebody can explain what is the difference in article code or category relationships between these types of categories (between [*,.] and [A,B,C])...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When assigning categories to MediaWiki pages, say South Sudan, you can use the syntax `[[Category:Countries|Sudan]]`, to make it sort under Sudan rather than the default (South Sudan). On Wikipedia, this is frequently used to put the “main page” of a category on top of the category page, by adding a sortkey like `*`, `-`, or similar (characters normally used, as well as the definition of a main page, will vary depending on what Wikipedia edition you are looking at).

When asking the API for members of a category, use `cmsort=sortkeyprefix` to sort the results accordingly. Furthermore, you can use `cmendsortkey` to stop at a certain sortkey, e.g. `1` or `A`. Or you can print out the sortkeys, and filter the list on your side, using `cmprop=sortkeyprefix`: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Physics&cmsort=sortkey&cmprop=sortkeyprefix|title

This is all very well documented in [the official MediaWiki documentation](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Categorymembers).

In the above example, the first five pages have a special sortkey (a space), to indicate that they are some kind of main pages to that category.